# Gradle sync failed: Failed to find CMake

Tags: android-studio, cmake

[image: aqui aparece todo el error en la parte de abajo***texto en negrita***]

Hola amigos soy nuevo por aca y también en el mundo de la programación hice un curso de desarrollador web y ahora estoy en uno de desarrollo de apps en android studio lo cual estoy desde cero acabo de instalar android estudio y me da este error:

> Gradle sync failed: Failed to find CMake

quisiera saber si alguien ya tiene respuestas para estos de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: El problema es de CMake, el error te lo dice clarito, `fallo al buscar CMake`, tienes instalado CMake ?

Answer (score 0):

Da click en el texto azul para instalar `CMake`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con esto tu proyecto funcionara sin problema.